# UIPIckerViews working together in one UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uipickerview, swift5

looked at the other similar questions but have not found the answers there.  Sorted out some of the issues I had but still have the issue where the data from the first pickerView determines what selections there are in the second pickerView (this part of app is a units convertor).

I understand what is going wrong but cannot see how to fix the problem.  Through print statements I can see that when I change the first pickerView, the value which holds the number of rows in the second pickerView changes.  But the second pickerView titles do not change so that when I go to an item that is higher than index number in the new array, the app crashes.  This is confirmed by the error Index out of range.

I have included code and a snapshot of what the pickerViews look like (no formatting or making it pretty - like to get functionality first).

Thanks for any help.

[image]

```
import UIKit
```

import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

```
var conversionTypes = ["length", "mass", "area", "volume", "rate", "temp", "pressure"]
var conversionItems = [["metres", "feet", "yard", "inch", "cm"], ["kg", "lbs", "tonne", "ounces"], ["ft2", "m2", "in2"], ["US Gall", "UK Gall", "Bbls", "ft3", "m3"], ["bbl/min", "scf/min", "scf/hr"], ["degC", "degF", "Kelvin"], ["bar", "psi"]]
var littlePickerType = 0
var wheelOne = 0
var wheelTwo = 0



@IBOutlet weak var numberToConvert: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var answerLabel: UILabel!


@IBOutlet weak var littlePicker: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var bigPicker: UIPickerView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    littlePicker.delegate = self
    littlePicker.dataSource = self
    bigPicker.delegate = self
    bigPicker.dataSource = self

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self.view, action: #selector(UIView.endEditing))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}


func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    if pickerView == littlePicker {
        return 1
    } else if pickerView == bigPicker {
        return 2
    }

    return 1
}


func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if pickerView == littlePicker {
        return conversionTypes.count
    } else if pickerView == bigPicker {
        return conversionItems[littlePickerType].count
    }

    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    if pickerView == littlePicker {
        return conversionTypes[row]
    } else if pickerView == bigPicker {
        return conversionItems[littlePickerType][row]
    }
    return ""
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    if pickerView == littlePicker {
        littlePickerType = row
    } else if pickerView == bigPicker {
        if component == 0 {
            wheelOne = row
        } else if component == 1 {
            wheelTwo = row
        }
    }

    print ("Conversion Type \(littlePickerType) WheelOne \(wheelOne) WheelTwo \(wheelTwo) count \(conversionItems[littlePickerType].count)")


}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be calling [`reloadAllComponents`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerview/1614380-reloadallcomponents) on your big picker whenever `littlePickerType` changes. This causes all the picker view data source methods (especially `titleForRow`) to be called again for the big picker.

```
var littlePickerType = 0 {
    didSet {
        bigPicker.reloadAllComponents()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for that, been scratching my head for a few hours, checked documentation and google and on here.